# PHP - urldecode - utf8 string?

Tags: php, urldecode

A website I am working on is displaying Crylic characters incorrectly. I don't know why. It doesn't appear to be a character encoding problem. The page title is in Crylic and appears fine. It is just the urldecoded string which is displaying incorrectly.

Locally I made a demo to see if I could determine what was going on.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$str = '%3CTEXTFORMAT%20LEADING%3D%222%22%3E%3CP%20ALIGN%3D%22JUSTIFY%22%3E%3CFONT%20FACE%3D%22Arial%22%20SIZE%3D%2212%22%20COLOR%3D%22%23000000%22%20LETTERSPACING%3D%220%22%20KERNING%3D%220%22%3E%D0%97%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B5!%3C%2FFONT%3E%3C%2FP%3E%3C%2FTEXTFORMAT%3E%3CTEXTFORMAT%20LEADING%3D%222%22%3E%3CP%20ALIGN%3D%22JUSTIFY%22%3E%3CFONT%20FACE%3D%22Arial%22%20SIZE%3D%2212%22%20COLOR%3D%22%23000000%22%20LETTERSPACING%3D%220%22%20KERNING%3D%220%22%3E%3C%2FFONT%3E%3C%2FP%3E%3C%2FTEXTFORMAT%3E%3CTEXTFORMAT%20LEADING%3D%222%22%3E%3CP%20ALIGN%3D%22JUSTIFY%22%3E%3CFONT%20FACE%3D%22Arial%22%20SIZE%3D%2212%22%20COLOR%3D%22%23000000%22%20LETTERSPACING%3D%220%22%20KERNING%3D%220%22%3E%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%20%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%82%20%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB%2C%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B4%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%92%D0%B0%D1%81%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BC%20%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B5!%20%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D0%92%D1%8B%20%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%20%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C%2C%20%D1%8F%20-%20%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84.%20%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%2C%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BE%20%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%BC%20%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B1%D0%B8%2C%20%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%20%D1%81%202005%20%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%20%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%8F%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F.%20%D0%98%20%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%2C%20%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B9%20%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%20%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B5%20%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE!%20%D0%9D%D0%B0%20%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%20%D1%8F%20%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%83%20%D0%B8%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8E%20%D0%B2%20%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B5.%20%D0%98%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B4%20%D0%B2%20%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%20%D0%B2%202006%20%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%20%D0%B2%D0%BE%20%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BC%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BB%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D1%82%D0%BE%2C%20%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D1%8F%20%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%20%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5%20%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8%20%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B8%2C%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%20%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5%20-%20%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B8!%20%3C%2FFONT%3E%3C%2FP%3E%3C%2FTEXTFORMAT%3E%3CTEXTFORMAT%20LEADING%3D%222%22%3E%3CP%20ALIGN%3D%22JUSTIFY%22%3E%3CFONT%20FACE%3D%22Arial%22%20SIZE%3D%2212%22%20COLOR%3D%22%23000000%22%20LETTERSPACING%3D%220%22%20KERNING%3D%220%22%3E%3C%2FFONT%3E%3C%2FP%3E%3C%2FTEXTFORMAT%3E%3CTEXTFORMAT%20LEADING%3D%222%22%3E%3CP%20ALIGN%3D%22JUSTIFY%22%3E%3CFONT%20FACE%3D%22Arial%22%20SIZE%3D%2212%22%20COLOR%3D%22%23000000%22%20LETTERSPACING%3D%220%22%20KERNING%3D%220%22%3E%D0%97%D0%B0%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%206%20%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D1%8F%20%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%BB%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%20%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B1%2C%20%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%2C%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%2C%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%20%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%20%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BC!%20%D0%AD%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%8B%D1%82%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%B2%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%B8%20%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%BE%20%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%2C%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%8F.%20%D0%94%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%8E%2C%20%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B8%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%83%D1%82%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8%20%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%20%D0%B8%D0%B7%20%D0%92%D0%B0%D1%81%2C%20%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC%20%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0.%3C%2FFONT%3E%3C%2FP%3E%3C%2FTEXTFORMAT%3E%3CTEXTFORMAT%20LEADING%3D%222%22%3E%3CP%20ALIGN%3D%22JUSTIFY%22%3E%3CFONT%20FACE%3D%22Arial%22%20SIZE%3D%2212%22%20COLOR%3D%22%230000FF%22%20LETTERSPACING%3D%220%22%20KERNING%3D%220%22%3E%3CA%20HREF%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.happywedding.cz%2Fblog%2F%3Fp%3D2787%22%20TARGET%3D%22_blank%22%3E%D0%92%20%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D1%8C%D1%8E%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8%20Happywedding%3C%2FA%3E%3CFONT%20COLOR%3D%22%23000000%22%3E%20%20%D1%8F%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%BE%20%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%2C%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D0%B2%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B5%20%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B6%D1%83%20%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E%20%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%8E.%3CFONT%20COLOR%3D%22%230000FF%22%3E%3C%2FFONT%3E%3C%2FFONT%3E%3C%2FFONT%3E%3C%2FP%3E%3C%2FTEXTFORMAT%3E%3CTEXTFORMAT%20LEADING%3D%222%22%3E%3CP%20ALIGN%3D%22JUSTIFY%22%3E%3CFONT%20FACE%3D%22Arial%22%20SIZE%3D%2212%22%20COLOR%3D%22%23000000%22%20LETTERSPACING%3D%220%22%20KERNING%3D%220%22%3E%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%20%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%2C%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%83%D1%8E%20%D0%92%D0%B0%D0%BC%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%3CFONT%20COLOR%3D%22%230000FF%22%3E%3CA%20HREF%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.happywedding.cz%2Fblog%2F%3Fp%3D812%22%20TARGET%3D%22_blank%22%3E%20%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%8E%2C%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E%20%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%20%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%20%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%26quot%3B%D0%92%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%26quot%3B%20%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B0%3C%2FA%3E%3C%2FFONT%3E%20-%20%D1%8F%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%8B%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B5%20%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8E%2C%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B5...%3C%2FFONT%3E%3C%2FP%3E%3C%2FTEXTFORMAT%3E%3CTEXTFORMAT%20LEADING%3D%222%22%3E%3CP%20ALIGN%3D%22JUSTIFY%22%3E%3CFONT%20FACE%3D%22Arial%22%20SIZE%3D%2212%22%20COLOR%3D%22%23000000%22%20LETTERSPACING%3D%220%22%20KERNING%3D%220%22%3E%3C%2FFONT%3E%3C%2FP%3E%3C%2FTEXTFORMAT%3E%3CTEXTFORMAT%20LEADING%3D%222%22%3E%3CP%20ALIGN%3D%22JUSTIFY%22%3E%3CFONT%20FACE%3D%22Arial%22%20SIZE%3D%2212%22%20COLOR%3D%22%23000000%22%20LETTERSPACING%3D%220%22%20KERNING%3D%220%22%3E%D0%9D%D0%BE%2C%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%2C%20%D1%8F%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8E%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%20%D1%81%D0%BE%20%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%8C%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8.%20%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B8%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8B%20%D0%92%D1%8B%20%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%20%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%B8%20%D0%B2%20%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85%20%D0%B6%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%85%2C%20%D0%B8%20%D0%B2%20%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%2C%20%D0%B8%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%85%20%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85%20%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%2C%20%D0%B8%20%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%85%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%20%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F%20%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85!%20%D0%AF%20-%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%20%D0%B8%20%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%8E%20%D1%82%D0%BE%2C%20%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%8E%20%D0%B8%20%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B1%D0%BB%D1%8E.%20%D0%9D%D0%BE%20%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%2C%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B5%20%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%20%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F%20%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%20%D0%B2%20%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B8%20%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%20%D1%81%20%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B4%D1%8C%D0%BC%D0%B8%2C%20%D1%81%20%D0%B8%D1%85%20%D1%87%D1%83%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%2C%20%D1%8D%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B8%20%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B8%2C%20%D1%81%20%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%2C%20%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%85%2C%20%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B5.%20%D0%92%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%8C%20%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%B2%20%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%B2%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%20%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BC%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BC%2C%20%D0%B0%20%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%2C%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%20%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D0%B2%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BC%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8.%3C%2FFONT%3E%3C%2FP%3E%3C%2FTEXTFORMAT%3E%3CTEXTFORMAT%20LEADING%3D%222%22%3E%3CP%20ALIGN%3D%22JUSTIFY%22%3E%3CFONT%20FACE%3D%22Arial%22%20SIZE%3D%2212%22%20COLOR%3D%22%23000000%22%20LETTERSPACING%3D%220%22%20KERNING%3D%220%22%3E%3C%2FFONT%3E%3C%2FP%3E%3C%2FTEXTFORMAT%3E%3CTEXTFORMAT%20LEADING%3D%222%22%3E%3CP%20ALIGN%3D%22JUSTIFY%22%3E%3CFONT%20FACE%3D%22Arial%22%20SIZE%3D%2212%22%20COLOR%3D%22%23000000%22%20LETTERSPACING%3D%220%22%20KERNING%3D%220%22%3E%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%88%D1%83%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%2C%20%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BB%20%D0%92%D0%B0%D1%81%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B8!%20%D0%9F%D0%BE%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8E%20%D1%8F%20-%20%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%BA-%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%BA%2C%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%20%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%20%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BB%20%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%20%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BC%20%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85%20%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%B8%20%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%20%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%2C%20%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83%20%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%B8%20%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%3A)%20%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%2C%20%D1%8F%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D1%81%20%D0%92%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%20%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%20%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B8%20%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B8%2C%20%D0%BD%D0%BE%2C%20%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%8E%2C%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B5%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%20%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B6%D1%83%D1%82%20%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B8%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8B.%3C%2FFONT%3E%3C%2FP%3E%3C%2FTEXTFORMAT%3E%3CTEXTFORMAT%20LEADING%3D%222%22%3E%3CP%20ALIGN%3D%22JUSTIFY%22%3E%3CFONT%20FACE%3D%22Arial%22%20SIZE%3D%2212%22%20COLOR%3D%22%23000000%22%20LETTERSPACING%3D%220%22%20KERNING%3D%220%22%3E%3C%2FFONT%3E%3C%2FP%3E%3C%2FTEXTFORMAT%3E%3CTEXTFORMAT%20LEADING%3D%222%22%3E%3CP%20ALIGN%3D%22JUSTIFY%22%3E%3CFONT%20FACE%3D%22Arial%22%20SIZE%3D%2212%22%20COLOR%3D%22%23000000%22%20LETTERSPACING%3D%220%22%20KERNING%3D%220%22%3E%D0%A3%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%20%D0%92%D0%B0%D0%BC%20%D0%B8%20%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%85%20%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2!%3C%2FFONT%3E%3C%2FP%3E%3C%2FTEXTFORMAT%3E%3CTEXTFORMAT%20LEADING%3D%222%22%3E%3CP%20ALIGN%3D%22JUSTIFY%22%3E%3CFONT%20FACE%3D%22Arial%22%20SIZE%3D%2212%22%20COLOR%3D%22%23000000%22%20LETTERSPACING%3D%220%22%20KERNING%3D%220%22%3E%D0%91%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BC%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B8!%3C%2FFONT%3E%3C%2FP%3E%3C%2FTEXTFORMAT%3E%3CTEXTFORMAT%20LEADING%3D%222%22%3E%3CP%20ALIGN%3D%22JUSTIFY%22%3E%3CFONT%20FACE%3D%22Arial%22%20SIZE%3D%2212%22%20COLOR%3D%22%23000000%22%20LETTERSPACING%3D%220%22%20KERNING%3D%220%22%3E%D0%98%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%92%D0%B0%D1%88%2C%3C%2FFONT%3E%3C%2FP%3E%3C%2FTEXTFORMAT%3E%3CTEXTFORMAT%20LEADING%3D%222%22%3E%3CP%20ALIGN%3D%22JUSTIFY%22%3E%3CFONT%20FACE%3D%22Arial%22%20SIZE%3D%2212%22%20COLOR%3D%22%23000000%22%20LETTERSPACING%3D%220%22%20KERNING%3D%220%22%3E%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB%20%D0%9A%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2.%3C%2FFONT%3E%3C%2FP%3E%3C%2FTEXTFORMAT%3E';

echo urldecode($str);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

This works fine. I uploaded to the clients host and again. It display's incorrectly. Does anyone know why this is? Does urldecode change between PHP versions? Where do I go next to troubleshoot this?

Comment: We need more details to be able to answer this. It could be a thousand different things.

Comment: check the encoding set by the client's hosts. Maybe it's not utf-8. use firebug to check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this **header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");**

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");
$str = '%3CTEXTFORMAT%20LEADING%3D%222%22%3E%3CP%20ALIGN%3D%22JUSTIFY%22%3E%3CFONT%20FACE%3D%22Arial%22%20SIZE%3D%2212%22%20COLOR%3D%22%23000000%22%20LETTERSPACING%3D%220%22%20KERNING%3D%220%22%3E%D0%97%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B5!%3C%2FFONT%3E%3C%2FP%3E%3C%2FTEXTFORMAT%3E%3CTEXTFORMAT%20LEADING%3D%222%22%3E%3CP%20ALIGN%3D%22JUSTIFY%22%3E%3CFONT%20FACE%3D%22Arial%22%20SIZE%3D%2212%22%20COLOR%3D%22%23000000%22%20LETTERSPACING%3D%220%22%20KERNING%3D%220%22%3E%3C%2FFONT%3E%3C%2FP%3E%3C%2FTEXTFORMAT%3E%3CTEXTFORMAT%20LEADING%3D%222%22%3E%3CP%20ALIGN%3D%22JUSTIFY%22%3E%3CFONT%20FACE%3D%22Arial%22%20SIZE%3D%2212%22%20COLOR%3D%22%23000000%22%20LETTERSPACING%3D%220%22%20KERNING%3D%220%22%3E%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%20%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%82%20%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB%2C%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B4%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%92%D0%B0%D1%81%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BC%20%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B5!%20%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D0%92%D1%8B%20%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%20%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C%2C%20%D1%8F%20-%20%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84.%20%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%2C%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BE%20%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%BC%20%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B1%D0%B8%2C%20%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%20%D1%81%202005%20%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%20%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%8F%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F.%20%D0%98%20%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%2C%20%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B9%20%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%20%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B5%20%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE!%20%D0%9D%D0%B0%20%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%20%D1%8F%20%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%83%20%D0%B8%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8E%20%D0%B2%20%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B5.%20%D0%98%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B4%20%D0%B2%20%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%20%D0%B2%202006%20%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%20%D0%B2%D0%BE%20%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BC%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BB%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D1%82%D0%BE%2C%20%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D1%8F%20%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%20%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5%20%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8%20%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B8%2C%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%20%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5%20-%20%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B8!%20%3C%2FFONT%3E%3C%2FP%3E%3C%2FTEXTFORMAT%3E%3CTEXTFORMAT%20LEADING%3D%222%22%3E%3CP%20ALIGN%3D%22JUSTIFY%22%3E%3CFONT%20FACE%3D%22Arial%22%20SIZE%3D%2212%22%20COLOR%3D%22%23000000%22%20LETTERSPACING%3D%220%22%20KERNING%3D%220%22%3E%3C%2FFONT%3E%3C%2FP%3E%3C%2FTEXTFORMAT%3E%3CTEXTFORMAT%20LEADING%3D%222%22%3E%3CP%20ALIGN%3D%22JUSTIFY%22%3E%3CFONT%20FACE%3D%22Arial%22%20SIZE%3D%2212%22%20COLOR%3D%22%23000000%22%20LETTERSPACING%3D%220%22%20KERNING%3D%220%22%3E%D0%97%D0%B0%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%206%20%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D1%8F%20%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%BB%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%20%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B1%2C%20%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%2C%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%2C%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%20%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%20%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BC!%20%D0%AD%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%8B%D1%82%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%B2%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%B8%20%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%BE%20%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%2C%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%8F.%20%D0%94%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%8E%2C%20%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B8%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%83%D1%82%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8%20%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%20%D0%B8%D0%B7%20%D0%92%D0%B0%D1%81%2C%20%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC%20%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0.%3C%2FFONT%3E%3C%2FP%3E%3C%2FTEXTFORMAT%3E%3CTEXTFORMAT%20LEADING%3D%222%22%3E%3CP%20ALIGN%3D%22JUSTIFY%22%3E%3CFONT%20FACE%3D%22Arial%22%20SIZE%3D%2212%22%20COLOR%3D%22%230000FF%22%20LETTERSPACING%3D%220%22%20KERNING%3D%220%22%3E%3CA%20HREF%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.happywedding.cz%2Fblog%2F%3Fp%3D2787%22%20TARGET%3D%22_blank%22%3E%D0%92%20%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D1%8C%D1%8E%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8%20Happywedding%3C%2FA%3E%3CFONT%20COLOR%3D%22%23000000%22%3E%20%20%D1%8F%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%BE%20%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%2C%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D0%B2%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B5%20%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B6%D1%83%20%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E%20%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%8E.%3CFONT%20COLOR%3D%22%230000FF%22%3E%3C%2FFONT%3E%3C%2FFONT%3E%3C%2FFONT%3E%3C%2FP%3E%3C%2FTEXTFORMAT%3E%3CTEXTFORMAT%20LEADING%3D%222%22%3E%3CP%20ALIGN%3D%22JUSTIFY%22%3E%3CFONT%20FACE%3D%22Arial%22%20SIZE%3D%2212%22%20COLOR%3D%22%23000000%22%20LETTERSPACING%3D%220%22%20KERNING%3D%220%22%3E%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%20%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%2C%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%83%D1%8E%20%D0%92%D0%B0%D0%BC%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%3CFONT%20COLOR%3D%22%230000FF%22%3E%3CA%20HREF%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.happywedding.cz%2Fblog%2F%3Fp%3D812%22%20TARGET%3D%22_blank%22%3E%20%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%8E%2C%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E%20%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%20%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%20%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%26quot%3B%D0%92%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%26quot%3B%20%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B0%3C%2FA%3E%3C%2FFONT%3E%20-%20%D1%8F%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%8B%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B5%20%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8E%2C%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B5...%3C%2FFONT%3E%3C%2FP%3E%3C%2FTEXTFORMAT%3E%3CTEXTFORMAT%20LEADING%3D%222%22%3E%3CP%20ALIGN%3D%22JUSTIFY%22%3E%3CFONT%20FACE%3D%22Arial%22%20SIZE%3D%2212%22%20COLOR%3D%22%23000000%22%20LETTERSPACING%3D%220%22%20KERNING%3D%220%22%3E%3C%2FFONT%3E%3C%2FP%3E%3C%2FTEXTFORMAT%3E%3CTEXTFORMAT%20LEADING%3D%222%22%3E%3CP%20ALIGN%3D%22JUSTIFY%22%3E%3CFONT%20FACE%3D%22Arial%22%20SIZE%3D%2212%22%20COLOR%3D%22%23000000%22%20LETTERSPACING%3D%220%22%20KERNING%3D%220%22%3E%D0%9D%D0%BE%2C%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%2C%20%D1%8F%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8E%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%20%D1%81%D0%BE%20%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%8C%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8.%20%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B8%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8B%20%D0%92%D1%8B%20%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%20%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%B8%20%D0%B2%20%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85%20%D0%B6%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%85%2C%20%D0%B8%20%D0%B2%20%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%2C%20%D0%B8%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%85%20%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85%20%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%2C%20%D0%B8%20%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%85%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%20%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F%20%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85!%20%D0%AF%20-%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%20%D0%B8%20%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%8E%20%D1%82%D0%BE%2C%20%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%8E%20%D0%B8%20%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B1%D0%BB%D1%8E.%20%D0%9D%D0%BE%20%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%2C%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B5%20%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%20%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F%20%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%20%D0%B2%20%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B8%20%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%20%D1%81%20%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B4%D1%8C%D0%BC%D0%B8%2C%20%D1%81%20%D0%B8%D1%85%20%D1%87%D1%83%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%2C%20%D1%8D%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B8%20%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B8%2C%20%D1%81%20%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%2C%20%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%85%2C%20%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B5.%20%D0%92%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%8C%20%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%B2%20%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%B2%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%20%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BC%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BC%2C%20%D0%B0%20%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%2C%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%20%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D0%B2%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BC%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8.%3C%2FFONT%3E%3C%2FP%3E%3C%2FTEXTFORMAT%3E%3CTEXTFORMAT%20LEADING%3D%222%22%3E%3CP%20ALIGN%3D%22JUSTIFY%22%3E%3CFONT%20FACE%3D%22Arial%22%20SIZE%3D%2212%22%20COLOR%3D%22%23000000%22%20LETTERSPACING%3D%220%22%20KERNING%3D%220%22%3E%3C%2FFONT%3E%3C%2FP%3E%3C%2FTEXTFORMAT%3E%3CTEXTFORMAT%20LEADING%3D%222%22%3E%3CP%20ALIGN%3D%22JUSTIFY%22%3E%3CFONT%20FACE%3D%22Arial%22%20SIZE%3D%2212%22%20COLOR%3D%22%23000000%22%20LETTERSPACING%3D%220%22%20KERNING%3D%220%22%3E%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%88%D1%83%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%2C%20%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BB%20%D0%92%D0%B0%D1%81%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B8!%20%D0%9F%D0%BE%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8E%20%D1%8F%20-%20%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%BA-%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%BA%2C%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%20%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%20%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BB%20%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%20%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BC%20%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85%20%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%B8%20%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%20%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%2C%20%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83%20%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%B8%20%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%3A)%20%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%2C%20%D1%8F%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D1%81%20%D0%92%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%20%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%20%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B8%20%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B8%2C%20%D0%BD%D0%BE%2C%20%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%8E%2C%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B5%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%20%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B6%D1%83%D1%82%20%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B8%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8B.%3C%2FFONT%3E%3C%2FP%3E%3C%2FTEXTFORMAT%3E%3CTEXTFORMAT%20LEADING%3D%222%22%3E%3CP%20ALIGN%3D%22JUSTIFY%22%3E%3CFONT%20FACE%3D%22Arial%22%20SIZE%3D%2212%22%20COLOR%3D%22%23000000%22%20LETTERSPACING%3D%220%22%20KERNING%3D%220%22%3E%3C%2FFONT%3E%3C%2FP%3E%3C%2FTEXTFORMAT%3E%3CTEXTFORMAT%20LEADING%3D%222%22%3E%3CP%20ALIGN%3D%22JUSTIFY%22%3E%3CFONT%20FACE%3D%22Arial%22%20SIZE%3D%2212%22%20COLOR%3D%22%23000000%22%20LETTERSPACING%3D%220%22%20KERNING%3D%220%22%3E%D0%A3%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%20%D0%92%D0%B0%D0%BC%20%D0%B8%20%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%85%20%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2!%3C%2FFONT%3E%3C%2FP%3E%3C%2FTEXTFORMAT%3E%3CTEXTFORMAT%20LEADING%3D%222%22%3E%3CP%20ALIGN%3D%22JUSTIFY%22%3E%3CFONT%20FACE%3D%22Arial%22%20SIZE%3D%2212%22%20COLOR%3D%22%23000000%22%20LETTERSPACING%3D%220%22%20KERNING%3D%220%22%3E%D0%91%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BC%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B8!%3C%2FFONT%3E%3C%2FP%3E%3C%2FTEXTFORMAT%3E%3CTEXTFORMAT%20LEADING%3D%222%22%3E%3CP%20ALIGN%3D%22JUSTIFY%22%3E%3CFONT%20FACE%3D%22Arial%22%20SIZE%3D%2212%22%20COLOR%3D%22%23000000%22%20LETTERSPACING%3D%220%22%20KERNING%3D%220%22%3E%D0%98%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%92%D0%B0%D1%88%2C%3C%2FFONT%3E%3C%2FP%3E%3C%2FTEXTFORMAT%3E%3CTEXTFORMAT%20LEADING%3D%222%22%3E%3CP%20ALIGN%3D%22JUSTIFY%22%3E%3CFONT%20FACE%3D%22Arial%22%20SIZE%3D%2212%22%20COLOR%3D%22%23000000%22%20LETTERSPACING%3D%220%22%20KERNING%3D%220%22%3E%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB%20%D0%9A%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2.%3C%2FFONT%3E%3C%2FP%3E%3C%2FTEXTFORMAT%3E';
echo urldecode($str);
```

Comment: This does the trick! However, I said in my post that there is a Cyrillic title. When I add the header, the url_decoded content displays perfectly. However the the title. Which is just a string being printed out turns to question marks in black diamonds. Like it is being double encoded

Comment: try displaying your title with this **iconv("cp1252","UTF-8",$your_title);**

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to change the character encoding in the text editor to UTF-8 that you're using. Here is what it looks like in Programmers Notepad. Try to Google how to change the character encoding in your text editor.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I use SublimeText and the default encoding is utf-8. When I upload the utf-8 file to the host it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta Content-Type= "text/html"; charset='UTF-8'>
<?php
$str = '%3CTEXTFORMAT%20LEADING%3D%222%22%3E%3CP%20ALIGN%3D%22JUSTIFY%22%3E%3CFONT%20FACE%3D%22Arial%22%20SIZE%3D%2212%22%20COLOR%3D%22%23000000%22%20LETTERSPACING%3D%220%22%20KERNING%3D%220%22%3E%D0%97%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B5!%3C%2FFONT%3E%3C%2FP%3E%3C%2FTEXTFORMAT%3E%3CTEXTFORMAT%20LEADING%3D%222%22%3E%3CP%20ALIGN%3D%22JUSTIFY%22%3E%3CFONT%20FACE%3D%22Arial%22%20SIZE%3D%2212%22%20COLOR%3D%22%23000000%22%20LETTERSPACING%3D%220%22%20KERNING%3D%220%22%3E%3C%2FFONT%3E%3C%2FP%3E%3C%2FTEXTFORMAT%3E%3CTEXTFORMAT%20LEADING%3D%222%22%3E%3CP%20ALIGN%3D%22JUSTIFY%22%3E%3CFONT%20FACE%3D%22Arial%22%20SIZE%3D%2212%22%20COLOR%3D%22%23000000%22%20LETTERSPACING%3D%220%22%20KERNING%3D%220%22%3E%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%20%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%82%20%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB%2C%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B4%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%92%D0%B0%D1%81%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BC%20%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B5!%20%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D0%92%D1%8B%20%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%20%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C%2C%20%D1%8F%20-%20%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84.%20%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%2C%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BE%20%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%BC%20%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B1%D0%B8%2C%20%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%20%D1%81%202005%20%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%20%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%8F%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F.%20%D0%98%20%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%2C%20%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B9%20%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%20%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B5%20%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE!%20%D0%9D%D0%B0%20%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%20%D1%8F%20%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%83%20%D0%B8%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8E%20%D0%B2%20%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B5.%20%D0%98%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B4%20%D0%B2%20%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%20%D0%B2%202006%20%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%20%D0%B2%D0%BE%20%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BC%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BB%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D1%82%D0%BE%2C%20%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D1%8F%20%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%20%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5%20%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8%20%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B8%2C%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%20%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5%20-%20%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B8!%20%3C%2FFONT%3E%3C%2FP%3E%3C%2FTEXTFORMAT%3E%3CTEXTFORMAT%20LEADING%3D%222%22%3E%3CP%20ALIGN%3D%22JUSTIFY%22%3E%3CFONT%20FACE%3D%22Arial%22%20SIZE%3D%2212%22%20COLOR%3D%22%23000000%22%20LETTERSPACING%3D%220%22%20KERNING%3D%220%22%3E%3C%2FFONT%3E%3C%2FP%3E%3C%2FTEXTFORMAT%3E%3CTEXTFORMAT%20LEADING%3D%222%22%3E%3CP%20ALIGN%3D%22JUSTIFY%22%3E%3CFONT%20FACE%3D%22Arial%22%20SIZE%3D%2212%22%20COLOR%3D%22%23000000%22%20LETTERSPACING%3D%220%22%20KERNING%3D%220%22%3E%D0%97%D0%B0%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%206%20%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D1%8F%20%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%BB%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%20%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B1%2C%20%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%2C%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%2C%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%20%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%20%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BC!%20%D0%AD%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%8B%D1%82%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%B2%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%B8%20%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%BE%20%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%2C%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%8F.%20%D0%94%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%8E%2C%20%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B8%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%83%D1%82%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8%20%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%20%D0%B8%D0%B7%20%D0%92%D0%B0%D1%81%2C%20%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC%20%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0.%3C%2FFONT%3E%3C%2FP%3E%3C%2FTEXTFORMAT%3E%3CTEXTFORMAT%20LEADING%3D%222%22%3E%3CP%20ALIGN%3D%22JUSTIFY%22%3E%3CFONT%20FACE%3D%22Arial%22%20SIZE%3D%2212%22%20COLOR%3D%22%230000FF%22%20LETTERSPACING%3D%220%22%20KERNING%3D%220%22%3E%3CA%20HREF%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.happywedding.cz%2Fblog%2F%3Fp%3D2787%22%20TARGET%3D%22_blank%22%3E%D0%92%20%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D1%8C%D1%8E%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8%20Happywedding%3C%2FA%3E%3CFONT%20COLOR%3D%22%23000000%22%3E%20%20%D1%8F%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%BE%20%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%2C%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D0%B2%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B5%20%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B6%D1%83%20%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E%20%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%8E.%3CFONT%20COLOR%3D%22%230000FF%22%3E%3C%2FFONT%3E%3C%2FFONT%3E%3C%2FFONT%3E%3C%2FP%3E%3C%2FTEXTFORMAT%3E%3CTEXTFORMAT%20LEADING%3D%222%22%3E%3CP%20ALIGN%3D%22JUSTIFY%22%3E%3CFONT%20FACE%3D%22Arial%22%20SIZE%3D%2212%22%20COLOR%3D%22%23000000%22%20LETTERSPACING%3D%220%22%20KERNING%3D%220%22%3E%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%20%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%2C%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%83%D1%8E%20%D0%92%D0%B0%D0%BC%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%3CFONT%20COLOR%3D%22%230000FF%22%3E%3CA%20HREF%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.happywedding.cz%2Fblog%2F%3Fp%3D812%22%20TARGET%3D%22_blank%22%3E%20%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%8E%2C%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E%20%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%20%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%20%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%26quot%3B%D0%92%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%26quot%3B%20%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B0%3C%2FA%3E%3C%2FFONT%3E%20-%20%D1%8F%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%8B%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B5%20%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8E%2C%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B5...%3C%2FFONT%3E%3C%2FP%3E%3C%2FTEXTFORMAT%3E%3CTEXTFORMAT%20LEADING%3D%222%22%3E%3CP%20ALIGN%3D%22JUSTIFY%22%3E%3CFONT%20FACE%3D%22Arial%22%20SIZE%3D%2212%22%20COLOR%3D%22%23000000%22%20LETTERSPACING%3D%220%22%20KERNING%3D%220%22%3E%3C%2FFONT%3E%3C%2FP%3E%3C%2FTEXTFORMAT%3E%3CTEXTFORMAT%20LEADING%3D%222%22%3E%3CP%20ALIGN%3D%22JUSTIFY%22%3E%3CFONT%20FACE%3D%22Arial%22%20SIZE%3D%2212%22%20COLOR%3D%22%23000000%22%20LETTERSPACING%3D%220%22%20KERNING%3D%220%22%3E%D0%9D%D0%BE%2C%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%2C%20%D1%8F%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8E%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%20%D1%81%D0%BE%20%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%8C%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8.%20%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B8%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8B%20%D0%92%D1%8B%20%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%20%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%B8%20%D0%B2%20%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85%20%D0%B6%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%85%2C%20%D0%B8%20%D0%B2%20%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%2C%20%D0%B8%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%85%20%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85%20%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%2C%20%D0%B8%20%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%85%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%20%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F%20%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85!%20%D0%AF%20-%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%20%D0%B8%20%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%8E%20%D1%82%D0%BE%2C%20%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%8E%20%D0%B8%20%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B1%D0%BB%D1%8E.%20%D0%9D%D0%BE%20%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%2C%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B5%20%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%20%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F%20%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%20%D0%B2%20%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B8%20%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%20%D1%81%20%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B4%D1%8C%D0%BC%D0%B8%2C%20%D1%81%20%D0%B8%D1%85%20%D1%87%D1%83%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%2C%20%D1%8D%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B8%20%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B8%2C%20%D1%81%20%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%2C%20%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%85%2C%20%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B5.%20%D0%92%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%8C%20%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%B2%20%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%B2%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%20%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BC%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BC%2C%20%D0%B0%20%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%2C%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%20%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D0%B2%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BC%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8.%3C%2FFONT%3E%3C%2FP%3E%3C%2FTEXTFORMAT%3E%3CTEXTFORMAT%20LEADING%3D%222%22%3E%3CP%20ALIGN%3D%22JUSTIFY%22%3E%3CFONT%20FACE%3D%22Arial%22%20SIZE%3D%2212%22%20COLOR%3D%22%23000000%22%20LETTERSPACING%3D%220%22%20KERNING%3D%220%22%3E%3C%2FFONT%3E%3C%2FP%3E%3C%2FTEXTFORMAT%3E%3CTEXTFORMAT%20LEADING%3D%222%22%3E%3CP%20ALIGN%3D%22JUSTIFY%22%3E%3CFONT%20FACE%3D%22Arial%22%20SIZE%3D%2212%22%20COLOR%3D%22%23000000%22%20LETTERSPACING%3D%220%22%20KERNING%3D%220%22%3E%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%88%D1%83%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%2C%20%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BB%20%D0%92%D0%B0%D1%81%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B8!%20%D0%9F%D0%BE%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8E%20%D1%8F%20-%20%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%BA-%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%BA%2C%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%20%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%20%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BB%20%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%20%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BC%20%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85%20%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%B8%20%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%20%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%2C%20%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83%20%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%B8%20%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%3A)%20%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%2C%20%D1%8F%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D1%81%20%D0%92%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%20%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%20%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B8%20%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B8%2C%20%D0%BD%D0%BE%2C%20%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%8E%2C%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B5%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%20%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B6%D1%83%D1%82%20%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B8%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8B.%3C%2FFONT%3E%3C%2FP%3E%3C%2FTEXTFORMAT%3E%3CTEXTFORMAT%20LEADING%3D%222%22%3E%3CP%20ALIGN%3D%22JUSTIFY%22%3E%3CFONT%20FACE%3D%22Arial%22%20SIZE%3D%2212%22%20COLOR%3D%22%23000000%22%20LETTERSPACING%3D%220%22%20KERNING%3D%220%22%3E%3C%2FFONT%3E%3C%2FP%3E%3C%2FTEXTFORMAT%3E%3CTEXTFORMAT%20LEADING%3D%222%22%3E%3CP%20ALIGN%3D%22JUSTIFY%22%3E%3CFONT%20FACE%3D%22Arial%22%20SIZE%3D%2212%22%20COLOR%3D%22%23000000%22%20LETTERSPACING%3D%220%22%20KERNING%3D%220%22%3E%D0%A3%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%20%D0%92%D0%B0%D0%BC%20%D0%B8%20%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%85%20%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2!%3C%2FFONT%3E%3C%2FP%3E%3C%2FTEXTFORMAT%3E%3CTEXTFORMAT%20LEADING%3D%222%22%3E%3CP%20ALIGN%3D%22JUSTIFY%22%3E%3CFONT%20FACE%3D%22Arial%22%20SIZE%3D%2212%22%20COLOR%3D%22%23000000%22%20LETTERSPACING%3D%220%22%20KERNING%3D%220%22%3E%D0%91%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BC%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B8!%3C%2FFONT%3E%3C%2FP%3E%3C%2FTEXTFORMAT%3E%3CTEXTFORMAT%20LEADING%3D%222%22%3E%3CP%20ALIGN%3D%22JUSTIFY%22%3E%3CFONT%20FACE%3D%22Arial%22%20SIZE%3D%2212%22%20COLOR%3D%22%23000000%22%20LETTERSPACING%3D%220%22%20KERNING%3D%220%22%3E%D0%98%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%92%D0%B0%D1%88%2C%3C%2FFONT%3E%3C%2FP%3E%3C%2FTEXTFORMAT%3E%3CTEXTFORMAT%20LEADING%3D%222%22%3E%3CP%20ALIGN%3D%22JUSTIFY%22%3E%3CFONT%20FACE%3D%22Arial%22%20SIZE%3D%2212%22%20COLOR%3D%22%23000000%22%20LETTERSPACING%3D%220%22%20KERNING%3D%220%22%3E%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB%20%D0%9A%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2.%3C%2FFONT%3E%3C%2FP%3E%3C%2FTEXTFORMAT%3E';
echo urldecode($str);
?>
```